# monitoring the backup

Tags: backup, monitoring, nagios, health-monitoring

Does anyone know any related work about:
1- Monitoring the backup done by HP Data Protector using Nagios or Icinga
2- Monitoring the backup done by HP Data Protector by any other monitoring tool
3- Monitoring the backup in general

Answer (score 0):

I think a good approach (generic) to monitor a (generic) backup is by doing several combined checks, assuming "backup" is a single file or directory:

1. Be sure the file is present in remote disk (by parsing filename, and using a regexp, for example).
2. Be sure the last one is max X days old (defined by you)
3. Be sure is min. X size (defined by you)

You have a open source (source available) remote backup checker plugin for Pandora FMS here:

http://pandorafms.com/index.php?sec=Library&sec2=repository&lng=es&action=view_PUI&id_PUI=359